# Composition of a negative operator and a positive one

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, operator-theory

Let $\Omega$ a bounded  open  set  of $R^n$,  $\omega$  a non-empty open subset of $\Omega$ and

$\chi_{\omega}  : L^2(\Omega)  \longrightarrow L^2(\omega)$
   be the restriction operator to $\omega$, while
   $\chi_{\omega}^*$ denotes the adjoint operator of $\chi_{\omega}$  and given by
   \begin{equation}\label{v1}
   (\chi_{\omega}^*y)(x)=\left\{
   \begin{array}{lll}
   y(x),\quad x\in \omega\\
   0, \quad otherwise 
   \end{array}
   \right.
   \end{equation}
   and denote $i_{\omega} = \chi_{\omega}^*\chi_{\omega}$ ($i_{\omega}$ is a positive operator).

On the other hand, let $A :\mathcal{D}(A)\subset L^2(\Omega)  \longrightarrow L^2(\Omega)$ be a linear
 unbounded operator such that $\langle Ay,y\rangle\leq 0, \forall y\in\mathcal{D}(A)$:

My question is : can we prove that $\langle i_{\omega}Ay,y\rangle\leq 0$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, of course not. Even if $A$ is bounded, this would imply that $i_\omega A$ is self-adjoint. So you only have a chance if $A$ and $i_\omega$ commute.